# Wordpress, why doesn't my blog load the posts if U use the /subfolder domain method?

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, blogs

I have a blog at http://hamids-it.elaosta.com amongst others. If I try to access it from

http://elaosta.com/hamids-it it loads the blog but says it couldn't find the page I wanted.

How do I fix this so I can use either?

Comment: Is this a WP multisite installation? Or a single installation in a subdomain?

Comment: Subdomain as per the answer by TheDeadMedic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a standard subdomain install, whereby `http://subdomain.example.com` is mapped to the directory `/example.com/public_html/subdomain`?

In any normal circumstance, say with a static HTML file, you can rightly access the same resource at both `example.com/subdomain/resource.html` and `subdomain.example.com/resource.html`.

**However**, in your case, WordPress is parsing the `REQUEST_URI` and using it to determine what to show.

So in the case of `http://elaosta.com/hamids-it`, WordPress is actually looking for a page 'hamids-it' - and if it doesn't find it, *voila*, your 404.

#### The fix?

You'll need to decide which way you want to access your blog, subdomain or sub-directory, **then stick to it**.

When you've made a choice, update your General settings in WordPress admin and set both address URL's to either `http://hamids-it.elaosta.com` **or** `http://elaosta.com/hamids-it`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have it already set using the subdomain method, I just assumed I could use both. Not the answer I wanted but correct none the less. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to use both!?